# SQL select last message

Tags: sql, optimization, query-optimization

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tMessages` (
 `tMessages_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `tUsers_sender_uid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `tUsers_recipient_uid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `tMessages_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `tMessages_text` varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`tMessages_id`),
 KEY `tUsers_sender_uid` (`tUsers_sender_uid`),
 KEY `tUsers_recipient_uid` (`tUsers_recipient_uid`),
 KEY `tUsers_uids` (`tUsers_sender_uid`,`tUsers_recipient_uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I need to:

1) Select all messages between two users and I did this:

```
SELECT * FROM `tMessages` FORCE INDEX (tUsers_uids) WHERE tUsers_sender_uid = 1 AND tUsers_recipient_uid=2 OR tUsers_sender_uid=2 AND tUsers_recipient_uid = 1
```

-- Is this a fast method?

2) Select last message in the ALL groups of messages between uid = 1 and another users

-- How I can do this?

Comment: `This is fast method` is not a question so why is there a question mark after it?

Comment: @IONIX, do You have an update for us on this? We worked hard to help you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This for the first part... need parenthesis?

```
SELECT * FROM `tMessages`
WHERE (tUsers_sender_uid = 1 AND tUsers_recipient_uid=2)
 OR (tUsers_sender_uid=2 AND tUsers_recipient_uid = 1)
```

The second part may be a bit more challenging.... but this should get you on the right track.

```
select coalesce(r.recipient, s.sender) OtherParty, 
    case when coalesce(r.`tMessages_id`,s.`tMessages_id`) > coalesce(s.`tMessages_id`,r.`tMessages_id`)
        then coalesce(r.`tMessages_id`,s.`tMessages_id`)
        else coalesce(s.`tMessages_id`,r.`tMessages_id`)
    end messageid
from
    (select `tUsers_recipient_uid` recipient, max(`tMessages_id`) `tMessages_id` 
    from `tMessages`
    where `tUsers_sender_uid` = 1
    group by `tUsers_recipient_uid`) r
full outer join (
    select `tUsers_sender_uid` sender, max(`tMessages_id`) `tMessages_id`
    from `tMessages`
    where `tUsers_recipient_uid`= 1
    group by `tUsers_sender_uid`) s
on r.recipient = s.sender
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.*  
  FROM tMessages m
  WHERE (tUsers_sender_uid = 1 AND tUsers_recipient_uid=2 OR tUsers_sender_uid=2 AND tUsers_recipient_uid = 1)
    and tMessages_timestamp = (select max(tMessages_timestamp) 
                                 from tMessages 
                                 WHERE (tUsers_sender_uid = 1 AND tUsers_recipient_uid=2 OR tUsers_sender_uid=2 AND tUsers_recipient_uid = 1));
```

Comment: It's between two users). i need all last messages where `tUsers_sender_uid` = 1 or `tUsers_recipient_uid` = 1

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select top(1)* from tMessages WHERE (tUsers_sender_uid = 1
AND tUsers_recipient_uid=2) OR (tUsers_sender_uid=2 AND 
tUsers_recipient_uid = 1) order by tMessages_timestamp desc
```

Answer (score 0):

This one will return All last messages between any 2 users:

```
SELECT m.*  
  FROM tMessages m
    where tMessages_timestamp = (select max(tMessages_timestamp) 
                                   from tMessages 
                                   WHERE (tUsers_sender_uid = m.tUsers_sender_uid    AND tUsers_recipient_uid = m.tUsers_recipient_uid OR 
                                          tUsers_sender_uid = m.tUsers_recipient_uid AND tUsers_recipient_uid = m.tUsers_sender_uid));
```

Answer (score 0):

This one will return All last messages between a certain user(i.e. 1) and any other user:

```
SELECT m.*  
  FROM tMessages m
    where m.tMessages_timestamp = (select max(tMessages_timestamp) 
                                   from tMessages 
                                   WHERE (tUsers_sender_uid = 1                      AND tUsers_recipient_uid = m.tUsers_recipient_uid OR 
                                          tUsers_sender_uid = m.tUsers_recipient_uid AND tUsers_recipient_uid = 1))
      and (m.tUsers_sender_uid = 1 or m.tUsers_recipient_uid = 1);
```